# How to decorate the intersection of two figures on TpX

Tags: graphics, plot

There is a way to plot something like that on [TpX](http://tpx.sourceforge.net)?

[image]

Comment: Please, is TpX just a typo or you really mean it? If so, what is it?

Comment: I'm serious. Can you help me in a way?

Comment: This is very old software, no longer maintained, whose primary purpose was converting and manipulating existing images.  It can export graphics suitable for inclusion in LaTeX; however, this is not strictly a LaTeX package.  At best it is not even a friend of LaTeX, but a casual stranger.  Recommend you use Tikz and LaTeX for this drawing.  See here http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/set-operations-illustrated-with-venn-diagrams/ for example venn diagram with working LaTeX code.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Some good software to draw according to latex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `tikz` if you don't mind:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[dashed]  (3,-0.5) circle (3cm and 2cm);
    \draw[dashed]  (0,0) circle (3cm and 2cm);
    \clip  (3,-0.5)circle (3cm and 2cm);
    \fill[dashed,pattern=north west lines]  (0,0) circle (3cm and 2cm);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Makes my eyes go funny ;).

Comment: That is Perfect! O.O

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of packages for drawing Venn diagrams. One is [venndiagram](http://ctan.org/pkg/venndiagram), which is based on TikZ.

This works for simple cases. For example:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=20pt,multi]{standalone}
\usepackage{venndiagram}
\begin{document}
\begin{venndiagram2sets}[labelA={}, labelB={}]
  \fillACapB
\end{venndiagram2sets}
\end{document}
```

[image: simple Venn]

The package provides commands for labelling, filling and annotating Venn diagrams depicting 2 or 3 sets. However, either I'm misunderstanding the documentation or some features are a little buggy, so be careful.

Another alternative is package [venn](http://ctan.org/pkg/venn) which is based on MetaPost. For usage details, read the source file which includes commented instructions.